# Matrix multiplication: Visualizing with an example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$
\begin {bmatrix}
1\\
3\\
2\\
1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$ ---------- (1)

There are four variables. The first is a 4x1 matrix and the second one 1x4 matrix. The resultant matrix after multiplication will be 4x4.

I try to visualize this way:
For 2x + 3y + 5z + 4t = 5;
4x + 7y + 2z + 5t = 8;
x + y + z + t = 1;
9x + 5y + 5z + 2t = 30.

$
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 5 & 4\\
4 & 7 & 2 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
9 & 5 & 5 & 2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$ \begin {bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
t\\
\end{bmatrix}$= $
\begin {bmatrix}
5\\
8\\
1\\
30\\
\end {bmatrix}
$           --------- (2)

In both the cases, there are four variables. While I can visualize the second one, how do I relate and make a connection with the first one.

Is it correct to view [1,3,2,1] as:
$
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end {bmatrix}?
$

Also, I do understand:
$
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$ $
\begin {bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
\end {bmatrix}
$=  $
\begin {bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
\end {bmatrix}
$

Is the below the same as above:

$
\begin {bmatrix}
1\\  
1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$  $
\begin {bmatrix}
2\\  
3\\
\end {bmatrix}
$ = $
\begin {bmatrix}
2\\  
3\\
\end {bmatrix}
$

Comment: What do you mean when you say visualize?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt I mean I can understand that if for 2 variables x and y, there is a coordinate plan with the values of x on x-axis and y on the y axis, a similar outcome translated for four variables.

Comment: The first expression can be evaluated using the Kronecker product. See Wikipedia. Very simple. What you do in the 2nd half of your question I don't understand. Making it unnecessarily complicated it seems.

Comment: Think of matrix multiplication as multiplying rows on the left by columns on the right. Each row.column is a dot product. Multiplication of the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column is in the $ij^{th}$ position in the answer. This will make sense if rows on the left are the same size as columns on the right. It tells you the answer must have the number of rows of the left matrix and number of columns of the right matrix. Your answer then has 4 rows and 4 columns, each entry a row (one number) times a column (1 number)

Comment: Might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Illustration

Comment: The things you think you understand, you don't understand. $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}\ne\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&3\cr}$. And you can't multiply $\pmatrix{1\cr1\cr}$ by $\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Revised my query.

Comment: OK. But it's not correct to view a one-row matrix as a $4\times4$ matrix, and my third sentence above still holds.

Comment: In your system of four equations, you have the variables $x,y,z,a$, but in the matrix representation of the system, you have $x,y,z,t$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Revised to t.

Comment: Here's an [interactive version](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/software/Matrix_Mult/index.html) of Jean-Claude's link.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted, Tech?

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand "While I can visualize the second one, how do I relate and make a connection with the first one." But I can answer the other questions:

No, it is not correct to view $[1,3,2,1]$ as $$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\cr0&3&0&0\cr0&0&2&0\cr0&0&0&1\cr}$$ The closest I can come to that is that sometimes people use the notation ${\rm diag}(1,3,2,1)$ for that $4\times4$ diagonal matrix.

And, no, $$\pmatrix{1\cr1\cr}\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}=\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}$$ is not the same as $$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}=\pmatrix{2\cr3\cr}$$ The second one is correct, the first one is not even wrong; the product of two matrices is only defined when the number of columns of the matrix on the left equals the number of rows of the matrix on the right.

[There is something called the *Hadamard product* of two matrices, and the first equation is correct for the Hadamard product, but there is no indication that OP was asking about, or even aware of, the Hadamard product. In any event, the Hadamard product is entirely different from the usual matrix product, and nowhere near as useful.]